# Roku Right-to-Left Language support

Tags: internationalization, roku

When internationalizing a Roku application, does the platform provide any built in support for RTL languages? With Android for example, you can define your UI element attributes to use start/end alignments, which are then aligned automatically (rtl, ltr) based on the users language setting.

I'm wondering if Roku provides anything like Android with regards to RTL support?

Edit: nevermind, looks like Roku only supports 4 languages right now, none of which are right to left